# Mapping/Area of an Image

Tags: complex-analysis

In $\mathbb{C}$, consider the neighborhood $O := \{x+yi; (x+1)^2 + (y-1)^2 < 4\}$ and the map $w = z^2$. In terms of area, what percentage of the image of $O$ consists of image points from multiple pre-images?

I understand that I'm looking for the area of all of the values that satisfy $w = z_1 ^2 = z_2 ^2$ where $z_1, z_2 \in O$, $w \in \mathbb{C}$, and $z_1 \ne z_2$. The problem that I am currently having is determining the boundary curve of the image so that I can compute an area. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The map $$w=z^2$$ maps both $z=Re^{i\theta}$ and $z=Re^{i(\theta+\pi)}$ to the same point (using the familiar polar representation of complex numbers). In your case, you have as domain a disk with radius 2 centered at $z=-1+i$ (call this domain $A$). Every point inside a disk with center at $0$ and radius $2-\sqrt{2}$ (call it $D$) have the property that:

i) To every point in $D$, there is another point in $D$ with phase difference of $\pi$ and same modulus;

ii) The pair of points in (i) is mapped to the same point in the $w$-plane;

iii) $D$ is inside $A$ and is tangent to it at $z=(\sqrt2 -1)+(1-\sqrt2)i$

You can draw a picture and convince yourself that these three properties suffices to say that the percentage you ask is the area of $D$ divided by the area of $S$. The result is $$\frac{(2-\sqrt2)^2}{2^2}\approx8,5\%$$